# Gson implementation no.of classes depends on curley braces?

Tags: java, android, gson

I have to get a Json string like this..

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":"5"}}}
```

Now from the Gson documentation i was able generate the String.But i needed three classes to generate it,Anything wrong with my implementation,Is there any possible way to reduce the classes for the same implementation,

Please find classes used to generate this..

```
public class c { String c="5";}

public class b {
@SerializedName("b")
c cobj = new c();}

public class a {
 @SerializedName("a")
b cobj =new b();}

public static void main (String args[]){
    Gson gs=new Gson();
    a aobj=new a();
    System.out.println(gs.toJson(aobj));
}
```

Kindly assist...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong.  In JSON, the `{}` indicates an object, so your string gives you three nested objects.  See the [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/)

If you are looking for inner classes, `static` inner classes work out of the box for both serialization and deserialization.  Not sure the following is that much shorter than what you have because three sets of braces implies three classes. Since your field names are different, it implies three distinct classes, and your internal data structures should be developed to make logical sense, not just "shorter"

You can get rid of your annotations by some renaming the fields so they match the fields you want.

```
class TopObj {
    static class AClass {
        static class BClass {
            String c = "5";
        };    
        B b = new b();
    };    
    a a = new a();
};
```

An alternative view is that all three classes are the same class type, but are just using different fields.  Only fields that have values are populated when converting to JSON.  As stated above, you data implies distinct classes, but you can do it with one class definition --

```
class Trickery {    
    Trickery a;
    Trickery b;
    String c;
};
```

Then you only use the fields as stated,

```
Trickery top = new Trickery();
top.a = new Trickery();
top.a.b = new Trickery();
top.a.b.c = "5";
System.out.println(gson.toJson(top));
```

Comment: Is there any way to reduce class structure...can we include inner classes?

Comment: Yes to inner classes.  Yes to class structure if you want to collapse to unused fields instead of additional classes.  See edits.  Really, you should go with what is the best data model from a usage standpoint, not just one that has less class definitions.